# How to get Mongo update query status in c#

Tags: asp.net, mongodb

I need to get the update query status means, whether the query executed successfully or not. How do i achieve this.

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> Updatecollection = 
                           MongoDBs.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName); 
Updatecollection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
```

this is the way i used to update my collection, Please help me to get the query status.

thanks in advance
Siva

Answer (score 0):

The `Update` method returns a `WriteConcernResult` object that contains the results of the update.

See the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/9cb94685-941c-28a5-ee6c-9dd5338741d9.htm) for the details of that object.

For example:

```
var result = Updatecollection.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Multi);
Console.WriteLine("{0} docs updated", result.DocumentsAffected);
```

Comment: Hi @JohnnyHK thanks for the reply, I used UpdatedExisting with my query and got the bool value, also tried with documentsAffected, it gives the count of affected documents. Will u please tell me how to get the query exception.